# Is it possible to use Office-connect with sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, office-connect

Is it possible to use Salesforce for office in sandbox ?

I would like to test before deploy my custom objects to production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that according to [SF Forum](http://success.salesforce.com/questiondetail?qId=a1X30000000HZZsEAO) this is possible

Two ways were suggested

```
1. With a registry edit.
> In Windows go to start -> run -> regedit ->   navigate to:
> HKey_Current_User > Software -> Salesforce.com -> SM ->  edit:  ServerUrl
> edit the url to say http://test.salesforce.com/.....  (just take the 'www' and replace with 'test')

2. Modify the URL in the XML file i found in program file (C:\Program     Files\salesforce.com\Office Edition\Resources\1033) and the one in my application data on   my documents & setting :C:\Documents and Settings\YOURUSER\Application   Data\salesforce.com\OfficeEdition\1036 and 1033.
Replace the www.salesforce.com by test.salesforce.com
```

*I have not tested this on my own though, as I do not use SFFO.

Comment: @GuilhermeGobetti - please upvote this answer as well as marking it correct.

Comment: @metadaddy I gave an upvote, did not he? if not, how I do? I'm learning to use this forum

Comment: Hi @GuilhermeGobetti - when I looked earlier, I could see the answer marked correct, but with zero votes, which seems odd (the message would be 'this is the right answer, but it wasn't helpful!). I see it with two votes now - no problem! Keep asking, answering and voting!